# Fortran. new gcc - "Bad value during floating point read"

Tags: gcc, fortran

I would like to use a very old program in Fortran 77. But a new version of gcc gives me error “Fortran runtime error: Bad value during floating point read”.
I need to read string to array. In past it was:

```
read(direc(2:ieq2-1),103) acent
103 format(3f12.7)
```

Where (direc(2:ieq2-1)=’(0.,0.,0.)’ and ieq2-1=8 and acent=(0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000).
What should I change?

Thank you very much for your answers!

A new version means:  gcc version 4.5.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4);
Declaration:

```
acent(1)=0.0
acent(2)=0.0
acent(3)=0.0
character*100 direc
```

Maxim

Comment: What does "new version of gcc" mean; i.e. post the version as output by "gfortran -v".

Comment: Secondly, can you post a self-contained example? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers!

A new version means: gcc version 4.5.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4); Declaration:

acent(1)=0.0
acent(2)=0.0
acent(3)=0.0
character*100 direc

Answer (score 3):

This would make some sense if direc(2:ieq2-1) were a string, in which case the read would be "internal IO", but the contents of the string should be numeric.   Without any parentheses.   Since you are using a format with field widths of 12, the values should be spaced out to fit into those fields.  It might be easier to use a list directed (format-free) read: read(direc(2:ieq2-1),*) acent.    How are direct and acent declared?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers!

A new version means:  gcc version 4.5.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4);
Declaration:
acent(1)=0.0
acent(2)=0.0
acent(3)=0.0
character*100 direc